Prometheus Monitoring when and how many messages were processed
Getting started beyond cpu and ram monitoring. I have event (kafka) consumer service.
Consider each message will have labels/attributes which are unique id and source=(app1 | app2 | appN).
I want monitor

Total number of messages processed (Count)
Rate of messages processed per source label per minute
When was the message processed for given id

I tried Implemented a counter with label containing id and source but it results in creating many counters with value 1. Thus I can sum (metric) to get total but cannot get rate.
Example metric:
message_count{app="nodejs-backend", source="app2", container="nodejs-backend", endpoint="web", id="app2@06:58:10.485102", instance="10.0.0.97:5000", job="nodejs-backend-service", namespace="default", pod="nodejs-backend-deployment-86c557d85c-ndj9j", service="nodejs-backend-service"}

If your id is indeed unique - Prometheus is a wrong tool to track your data.

Prometheus would be right for use if you can aggregate data: simply have a number of messages processed by each app in each pod. In that case counts and rates will be available, but not timestamp for each specific message. If timestamps are critical for you - consider using logging solution (Loki, for example) instead.
